# Does order of operations and computing modulo matter?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So I read that it does not matter.

Eg: Let $x=14$, $y=25$, $m=12$.

Operations first,computing modulo second: $(x+y)\bmod m=39\bmod12 =3$.

Computing modulo first, operations second: $x\bmod m= 14\bmod 12=2$, $y\bmod m=25\bmod12=1$. Then $1+2=3$.

Yup, seems that order doesn't matter.

---

But when I try with $x =8$, $y =5$, $m=12$. The results are different.

Operations first,computing modulo second: $(x+y)\bmod m=13\bmod12=1$.

Computing modulo first, operations second: $x\bmod m=8\bmod 12=8$, $y\bmod m=5\bmod 12=5$. Then $8+5=13$.

Does order then matter? It's kind of obvious I made some glaring silly mistake somewhere

---

Edit: I get that modular arithmetic "wraps around". Both the comments and answer states that $13\bmod 12=1$.

Here's what's confusing me: Doesn't doing  $13\bmod 12$ mean  that you are including an additional modulo operation?

Comment: $13\equiv 1 \pmod {12}$ so saying that $a\equiv 13\pmod {12}$ is the same as saying that $a\equiv 1 \pmod {12}$.

Comment: The "glaring, silly error" is that 13 (mod 12) **is** 1 so you do, in fact, get the same thing!

Comment: This kind of issue disappears almost completely if you stop thinking about modulo as an operation, and instead think about it as a relation; It is often much better to think about it as a way to compare two numbers, rather than a thing you do two numbers and then check whether the results are equal. You still can (and should) ask whether addition plays nicely with modulo, but the whole thing gets a lot tidier, and there is no question about "which one you do first".

Comment: @Arthur When you mean relations, do you mean the topic(I haven't learnt that)? And when you mean `often much better to think about it as a way to compare two numbers`, do you mean using modular equivalences like seeing the difference as a multiple of $n$?

Comment: @Leon Yes, I do mean modular equivalences.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking in terms of computing effort, then, yes, you would need to compare the steps in (a) calculating modulos, performing you arithmetic and then calculating the modulo of the answer with (b) do all the arithmetic first and only calculate the modulo of the answer.

Mathematically both procedures give the same result, but obviously (a) has potentially many more calculations.  On the other hand, if there are a lot of calculation in between, (b) might lead to very large intermediate numbers that either overflow your computer arithmetic or, if size itself is not an issue, take much longer to compute;  reducing numbers at each stage to their canonical modulo representation may make sense.

Hope that covers any points missed by other commentators.

Comment: If you could just include the points by the commentator, your answer would be so wholesome!

Comment: Hi. I only meant points in the other comments to your question.

Comment: Yup, what I mean is if it's possible for you to include those points in the other comments in your answer so that your answer would be wholesome?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, if you're working mod 12, then $13\equiv1$! Thus you didn't make any silly mistakes.

Another way to think about it is "clock arithmetic". If you move forwards from 8 o'clock by 5 hours, it's "13 o'clock" (13 hundred hours) -- which is just 1 o'clock.